# Remove /EFI/Ubuntu & NVRAM after dual boot cleanup

Tags: cleanup

After removing the Ubuntu partitions from my earlier Ubuntu & Windows 8.1 dual boot from my Asus UX-305FA laptop I now still can find the Ubuntu options in the boot menu. I was told that to solve the problem I need to "remove /EFI/Ubuntu from my ESP and NVRAM from my UEFI". I made a Ubuntu LiveUSB but have now no idea as how to proceed.

All help appreeciated.

Comment: Details here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your BIOS,  that is where your boot settings are stored. once it is reset, when you reboot run Boot-repair disk (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)   Follow instructions on LINK I gave you.